# How do I remove glitched areas and blocks?

Tags: blockheads

How can you remove glitched spots or blocks created by hackers removing items that they should not be able to remove?

A glitched area is an area that you can no longer place a block or you can't remove the item or block from that area :(

Answer (score 2):

In the 1.7 update (released on March 15<sup>th</sup> 2018), it added the `/repair` feature that world owners and administrators could use on servers. Type `/repair` into the chat, and you’ll be able to tap on glitched blocks and it will fix them.

NOTE: I haven’t tried this as I don’t own a server myself but I have seen posts on the forums about this feature.

Answer (score -1):

You can burn them by placing a fire under them!